# Accessing the input text field placed under the table cell <td>

Tags: html-table, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I am trying to access the text area placed under the tables  using robotframework and selenium. When done manually, user needs to double click on the table cell (inside div class="htContainer") before being able to access the text area (inside div class="handsontableInputHolder") and input some values.

Running the scripts to double click the table cell have passed results but the table cell was not actually double clicked and text area does not show, preventing it to be edited.

I have tried using the Double Click keyword from Selenium2Library in order to double click and access the text area

[Screenshot of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yk1Bc.png)

[image]

```
<div class="handsontable widerHandsontableRowHeader htCenter" id="electionPriceContainer">
   <div class="htContainer" style="position: relative;">
      <div class="wtHolder ht_master" style="position: relative; width: 330px; height: 46px;">
         <div class="wtHider" style="position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px;">
            <div class="wtSpreader">
               <table class="htCore">
                  <colgroup></colgroup>
                  <thead></thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <th class="">
                           <div class="relative"><span class="rowHeader">Reinvestment Price</span></div>
                        </th>
                        <td class="htCenter" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); background-color: rgb(169, 208, 245);"></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>

   </div>
   <div class="handsontableInputHolder" style="top: 0px; left: 0px; display: none;"><textarea class="handsontableInput" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></textarea></div>
</div>
```